# .mat file variable is overridden with save

Tags: matlab

I have a matlab file which contains these values :

[image]

Opening the file, here a snippet of X :

[image]

And y :

[image]

Deleting all rows in y and saving, need to replace the current file :

[image]

Replacing the file causes all of the X values to be removed also :

[image]

Can see from above the variable 'y' is no longer present.

How can edit a .mat file 'y' variable without removing the 'X' variable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`'-append'` option](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html#bt0xgur-6) when saving.

Doing `save('data.mat','x','-append')` or `save data.mat x -append`  will either append the data or substitute the variable without modifying the rest of the data.

Comment: so I need to use save('data.mat','x','-append') if updating 'x' and save('data.mat','y','-append') if updating 'y' , seems a bit convolated ?

Comment: @blue-sky I believe you can do `save('data.mat','x','y','z','-append')`. And will overwrite the three variables. I gave that example because it was what you asked. The idea is to just add the `'-append'` option to `save`

Answer (score 1):

If you have Matlab R2011b of later, you can also use the [`matfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matfile.html) function to get a dynamic handle to the data stored in the MAT-file.  This is typically reserved for large files with data that should only to be loaded into memory when needed, but the functionality is similar to using `save` and more interactive.  For your current example:

```
x = rand(5000,400);
y = rand(5000,1);
save('data.mat','x','y');
m = matfile('data.mat','Writable',true);
m.y = [];
```

And `y` in the MAT-file is automatically updated.